# PowerShell - formatting date to yyMMdd format

Tags: date, powershell, format

I run a PowerShell script that passes a parameter, such as "20160428".

I need to format this into yyMMdd (i.e., getting "160428" as the result). I could just strip out the "20", but I would like to get this right. For such I did so many attempts, such as:

```
#$COBDATE= '{0:yyMMdd}' -f $COBDATE
#$COBDATE = ([datetime]::ParseExact($COBDATE, "yyMMdd", [System.Globalization.CultureInfo]::InvariantCulture )).DayOfWeek
```

And the last one:

```
$COBDATE = ("{0:yyMMdd}" -f [datetime]::parse($COBDATE))
```

The below works, but once I replace "Get-Date" by my date "20160428" it just prints out the yyMMdd string.

```
$b = (Get-Date).AddDays(-1).ToString("yyMMdd")
```

So if I try this:

```
$input = "20160428"
$format = "yyMMdd"
$input_toDate_up = [DateTime]::ParseExact($input, $format, $null).ToString($format)
$input_toDate_up
```

It just says that the string is not a valid Date Time, which seems to be the root cause.

How can I fix this?

Comment: The format you describe with your example is `yyyyMMdd`, not `yyMMdd`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$Input = "20160428"
Get-Date -Year $Input.Substring(0,4) -Month $Input.Substring(4,2) -Day $Input.Substring(6,2) -Format "yyMMdd"
```

Comment: As ssaviers mentioned you should also use a variable other than $Input to avoid conflicts.

Comment: In my case I add to cast the parameter to string before ($cobdate = [string]$cobdate, but after that it worked perfectly, thanks!

Comment: What type was it before casting to a string? If $cobdate is already a datetime object you can simply do Get-Date -Date $cobdate -Format "yyMMdd"

Comment: supposedly it was a "Int32", as it was what was indicated by the error. That variable was extracted from the passed parameter when the the script is executed. Does it make sense?

Answer (score 1):

I think for one `$input` is a reserved variable so you shouldn't use it as nothing will really work in there as you expect. See here [about_Automatic_Variables](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh847768.aspx)

I have used this drawn out substring process before with varied abstract date formats.

```
$dateinput = "20160428"
$dateformat = "yyMMdd"

Get-Date($dateinput.Substring(4,2) + "/" + $dateinput.Substring(2,2) + "/" + $dateinput.substring(0,4)) -Format $dateformat
```

I'm sure there is a shorter regex method, but that is not under my hat yet.

Comment: @PeterMortensen was implying that I have had various source date formats that came from different log files or systems I have had to break up with substring extraction and create a logical date that would cast properly.